# How to flush a Scanner continuously?

Tags: java, stream, java.util.scanner, producer-consumer, flush

To apply a REGEX on stream, I'm using `scanner.findWithinHorizon`.
Obviously, I'm receiving some data through an Inputstream which is passed to a Scanner

```
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(response.getContentInputStream());
    do{
    extractedData=scanner.findWithinHorizon(PATTERN,0);
    // Perform some checks
    }while(extractedData!=null);
```

The checks I'm doing are performed on a blocking operation (synchronous) and non-blocking (asynchronous) as well.
In the first use case, the behavior is working as expected. Whereas, in case of asynchronous task, the scanner hold just a snapshot at t instant and the Inputstream may be fed by additional data.

Question: How can I flush the Scanner continuously to get the newest data ?

Comment: Not quite sure what's going on with your 'asynchronous' version but what's stopping you from using a new ```Scanner```  on each 'burst' of data?

Comment: Thank your @g00se for your answer. I simplified my question. In fact, I have spring filter which intercepts responses of asynchronous endpoint which return a ResponseBodyEmitter.
So, those endpoints send continuously data. I can't detect when data has been sent to create a new Scanner.